# For solids/liquids can $dP$ or $dV$ be assumed to be $0$ when calculating $\triangle H$ or $\triangle U$ by the following formulae?

Tags: thermodynamics

For solids/liquids can $dP$ or $dV$ be assumed to be $0$ when calculating $\triangle H$ or $\triangle U$ by the following formulae?

$$\triangle H=nC_p\triangle T + \int (\frac{\partial H}{\partial P})_vdP$$

or

$$\triangle U=nC_v\triangle T + \int (\frac{\partial U}{\partial V})_pdV$$

In some books I saw they take $dV$ as $0$ but not $dP$.Why?

Comment: Liquids are mostly incompressible under practical conditions. For very large variations in pressure, there is negligible variation in volume of the liquid.

Comment: @Lelouch this should be posted as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the material is considered incompressible, then dV = 0.  The general equation for $dH$ (molar) is:$$dH=C_pdT+V(1-\alpha T)dP$$where V is the molar volume, Cp is the molar heat capacity, and $\alpha$ is the coefficient of volumetric thermal expansion.  Even if the $\alpha T$ term is negligible compared to unity, the term VdP is not, because dP cannot be assumed to equal zero.

Answer (score 0):

Bulk modulus of a substance is a measure of its compressibility. It is given by $\beta$ = V.$\partial$P/$\partial$V where $\partial$V/V is the fractiaonal change in volume, for infinitesimal pressure change $\partial$P. For liquides, $\beta$ is very high having magnitudes of the order of $10^9$ Pa often. This means, that for a small change in pressure, the fractional change of volume in the denominator is very small, making $\beta$ very large. Thus, it is reasonable to assume V of a liquid to be constant over an appreciable range of pressure.